# Pass event to a sibling html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have created an app with three.js were there are 2 renderers (1 canvas and 1 div(css renderer)).
The css renderer is on top of the canvas and I would like to pass any type of event to the canvas element which is behind. So far I have failed to create a dispatcher...

What I have tried so far:

1)

```
// on top element css renderer 
$(this.cssRenderer.domElement).on("click mousedown mouseup mousemove focus blur keydown keyup change touchstart touchend touchmove", function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //canvas background domelement
    $(that.renderer.domElement).trigger(event);

});
```

2)

```
$(this.cssRenderer.domElement).on("click mousedown mouseup mousemove focus blur keydown keyup change touchstart touchend touchmove", function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    that.renderer.domElement.dispatchEvent(event.originalEvent);

});
```

In case 2 I get the following error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on
>   'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

I also tried to copy the object or pass it after some timeOut but nothing seem to work.
I haven't done anything similar so I'd like a little help or some guidance.

Comment: Why not remove the stopPropagation and leave it propagate ?  You only need that the cssrenderer is a child (or descendant) of the element where you set your canvas

Comment: I've tried putting the dispatchEvent call into a setTimeout, and it prevents that error. But it didn't seem to properly dispatch the event for some reason. Its parent got the event, but the node I dispatched to didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass `event` to your trigger function, as event is an object and trigger requires a string as an argument.

Instead, try passing `event.type` instead:

```
$(that.renderer.domElement).trigger(event.type);
```

[Read up here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncxvn3gy/2/) (or [with mouse coordinates](http://jsfiddle.net/ncxvn3gy/1/))

To also pass mouse coordinates I am passing an object (mouse) as well as the event type.

Comment: passing only the type is not good enough the coordinates of the mouse must be also passed

Comment: @Syd do you need the coordinates relative to the window, or the first element?

Comment: it doesn't make mush of a difference in my case since both elements are window sized all the time

Comment: @Syd Well then, my answer does everything you need. If you would like a better explanation, or more functionality, just ask.